# How can I receive email from Apple about APNs expiration email?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, app-store

[image]

At developer.apple.com,only the owner received this email,but the managements didn't.And then the APNs expired.

So How can the management receive this email?

Comment: please check my answer

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific settings available to enable sending mails to the Management until Apple changes the existing rules.

By default it will only send the Notifications to the Main Admin only or the other users who have same Admin Access. So we can't do any change into that settings.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have admin access but still, no mail was received. I think only the Account holder will receive it.